# Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a aspx webpage with C# and I'm trying to point to a directory but when I do so, I get "Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\2.txt'." But in my C# code, I am using:

```
currentStaffPosition = rolesRadioButton.SelectedItem.ToString();
string currentStaffDirectory = Server.MapPath(@"~\admin\applications\" + currentStaffPosition);
```

This code should point to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\admin\applications
Anyone know why or how this is happening? Thanks ahead of time.

Additional Code:

```
string currentStaffPosition = null;
string currentStaffDirectory = null;

protected void rolesRadioButton_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dropDownList.Items.Clear();
    currentStaffPosition = rolesRadioButton.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string currentStaffDirectory = Server.MapPath(@"~\admin\applications\" + currentStaffPosition);
    string[] staffApplications = Directory.GetFiles(currentStaffDirectory);
    foreach (string apps in staffApplications)
    {
        dropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(apps)));
    }
}

protected void dropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentSelectedApp = currentStaffDirectory + dropDownList.SelectedItem + ".txt";
    string currentLine;
    StreamReader applicationReader = new StreamReader(currentSelectedApp);
    while ((currentLine = applicationReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (currentLine.Contains("First Name:"))
            forumUsernameTextBox.Text = currentLine.Replace("First Name: ", "");
    }
    applicationReader.Close();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the value of `currentStaffPosition` and the code where `currentStaffDirectory` is used?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to open a file that located in the currentStaffDirectory. Just making currentStaffPosition still causes the problem to occur.